# Google apps script getRange() range not found error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I feel like I'm going about this in all the wrong way.  I'm trying to automate some of my workload here. I'm cleaning up spreadsheets with 4 columns (A-E), 2000+ rows. Column B contains website URLs, column D contains the URL's business name, generated from another source.

Sometimes the tool doesn't grab the name correctly or the name is missing, so it populates the missing entries in column D with "------" (6 hyphens). I've been trying to make a function that takes an input cell, checks if the contents of the cell are "------", and if it is the function changes the contents of the input cell to the contents of the cell two columns to the left (which is generally a website url). This is what I've come up with.

```
function replaceMissing(input) {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    //sets active range to the input cell
    var cell = sheet.getRange('"' + input + '"');
    //gets cell to fill input cell
    var urlCell = sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(), cell.getColumn() - 2);
    //gets contents of input cell as String
    var data = cell.getValue(); 
    //gets contents of urlCell as String
    var data2 = cell.getValue();


    //checks if input cell should be replaced
    if (data === "------") { 
      //set current cell's value to the value of the cell 2 columns to the left
      cell.setValue(data2);
    }
}
```

When I attempt to use my function in my sheet, the cell is returning the error

```
Error Range not found (line 4).
```

I'm assuming, based on similar questions people have asked, that this is how you use the A1 notation of the function with an argument. However, that doesn't seem to be the case, so I'm stuck. I also don't think my solution is very good period.

Comment: I am not disagreeing with the posted answer regarding performance or better solution, but the error you are getting is that "input" is undefined.Initializing var cell = sheet.getActiveCell(); will avoid the error. Also    you meant to code var data2 = urlCell.getValue(); I tried it with these changes and it worked.

Comment: You will need to grant permission for the script to set values (in what I said in the preceding comment).

Comment: An alternative that avoids scripting is if you do not mind introducing another column, assuming you have headers in line 1 and your data starts in line 2, you could put =if(D2="------",B2,D2) in a free column on line 2 and copy the formula all the way down. You could then hide column D if you wished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) It's somewhat ambiguous in GAS documentation, but custom functions have quite a few limitations. They are better suited for scenarios where you need to perform a simple calculation and return a string or a number type value to the cell. While custom functions can call some GAS services, this practice is strongly discouraged by Google.

If you check the docs for the list of supported services, you'll notice that they support only some 'get' methods for Spreadsheet service, but not 'set' methods https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions

That means you can't call cell.setValue() in the context of a custom function. It makes sense if you think about it - your spreadsheet can contain 1000s of rows, each with its own custom function making multiple calls to the server. In JavaScript, every function call creates its own execution context, so things could get ugly very quickly.

2)  For better performance, use batch operations and don't alternate between read / write actions. Instead, read all the data you need for processing into variables and leave the spreadsheet alone. After processing your data, perform a single write action to update values in the target range. There's no need to go cell by cell when you can get the entire range using GAS.

Google Apps Script - best practices
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices

Below is a quick code example that runs onOpen and onEdit. If you need more flexibility in terms of when to run the script, look into dynamically-created triggers https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app
Because your spreadsheets have lots of rows, you may hit the execution quota anyway - by using triggers you can work around the limitation.

Finally, if a cell containing '----' is a rare occurrence, it might be better to create another array variable with new values and row numbers to update than updating the entire range.
Personally, I think the single range update action would still be quicker, but you could try both approaches and see which one works best.

```
function onOpen(){

 test();


}

function onEdit() {

 test();

}


function test() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('yourSheetName');

  //range to replace values in
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 4, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1);

  //range to get new values from
  var lookupRange = range.offset(0, -2);

  //2d array of values from the target range
  var values = range.getValues();
  //2d array of values from the source range
  var lookupValues = lookupRange.getValues();   

  //looping through the values array and checking if array element meets our condition
  for (var i=0; i < values.length; i++) {

      values[i][0] = (values[i][0] == '------') ? lookupValues[i][0] : values[i][0];

  }

  // one method call to update the range
  range.setValues(values);

}
```

Comment: Solid answer. To clarify, for translating to the user's context, I believe: a) This assumes there is only one sheet in the workbook (otherwise you need a getActiveSheet() or potentially a number other than 0 in getSheets()[0], b) as indicated in your comment, in the user's example, your column 3 would be column 4, and c) your == '-' would be == '------'.

Comment: Thanks for the correction - I updated my answer.  Also, I'm not sure if the OP indeed uses custom functions. From what he wrote, it appears that he calls the function directly from the cell, in which case 'input' would be the actual value in the cell, so  var cell = sheet.getRange('"' + input + '"') would not work. cell.setValue() always seemst it throw an error when called from the custom function.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that about input. I guess it would be safer to say that when I tried the OP's function as a custom function, that was the source of the error I got. SetValue works in my custom function once I give permission. My guess is you did that too. It seems hard to believe setValues would work but setValue would not (but I may be missing some subtlety on function versus custom function).

Comment: Do you physically type the function in the spreadsheet cell, e.g. as in formula? For example, the following always fails for me  function MY_FUNC(input) {  var cell =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();                          
 cell.setValue(input); }  When I use MY_FUNC as a custom function (basically, a formula) by typing it in the cell like this  =MY_FUNC(5), I always get the error saying I don't have the permission to execute setValue(). It agrees with GAS documentation, so I'm curious how you got setValues() to work

Comment: No. (logged in to sheets) I went into Tools, Script Editor, and put the code there. Then I save (otherwise it kvetches "can't find myFunction"). Then I hit run. First time I get a popup "Authorization required
SO scratch needs your permission to access your data on Google.
". I click Review Permissions, sign in, and click ALLOW.

Comment: I see. Seems like the normal authorization flow for all functions. I was referring to the custom functions that you define in your script project, but can actually call from the sheet cell directly. From what the OP wrote,  I assumed he was using this technique